# Usage of 'Hi' and 'Dear' in Formal Communication

Tags: formality, email

I always hesitate using 'Hi' in formal mails. Is it OK to use it like "Hi Sir,..."?
Same with 'Dear Junior,...'.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your context is a bit scant.  Perhaps you can provide some more on what usage shapes your question.   Welcome to the site!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is requesting writing advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could start your first mail or two with "Hello [name]" and then switch to "Hi [name]" in future mails once you have established some rapport with the person. If you're in an environment where informal exchanges are encouraged, then you could start with "Hi [name]" in your communications.

"Dear Sir" or "Dear Madam" is always for formal communication where you do not intend to get to know the person well or cannot really form a personal rapport with the person (like for example, in the case of you being a service provider, say a bank, and addressing a customer or maybe you're in HR and are addressing an employee).

For addressing juniors, you could use "Hello" if you wish to be formal or "Hi" for informal communication.

Answer (score 6):

*Hi* is informal and *Dear . . .*. is formal, but *Sir* is formal and *Junior* is informal. It follows that *Hi Sir* and *Dear Junior* are mismatched. (I have to qualify that by saying that I can’t imagine anyone addressing anyone else in writing as *Junior*, but that is perhaps because it’s not used in British English.)

Comment: Junior can be (effectively) a given name.  By way of comparison "Dear Barrie" would not be formal, but at least sounds sensible.

Comment: Unlikely in British English.

Comment: I knew one in London - he had the same given name as his father, and was almost universally known as Junior, by school teachers for example.  That explains my "(effectively)". I think it was actually a middle name rather than a suffix, but it was a long time ago. Of course using a middle name as the preferred given name, for example in your email "from" field, is not uncommon.

Comment: By using "Dear Junior", i meant Junior will be replaced by any Name e.g. "Dear Nirav..."

Comment: @NiravRadia The name that you use after "Dear" has a significant impact on the formality of the greeting, so it's hard to use a single placeholder when asking your question. "Junior" clearly has connotations other than what you intended. You could also write "Dear So-and-so" (somewhat generic) or "Dear Sir/Madam" (formal) or "Dear Nirav" (less formal) or "Dear Daddy" (someone you have a close relationship with).

Comment: @BarrieEngland What could be the understood when someone writes me in an email without any title i.e. "Nirav, Please do this task before that one...(etc)"?

Comment: I don't think that's so unusual these days.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the recipient's title, then starting the conversation "Dear Mr/Ms/Dr/(whatever) Surname" is unlikely to be wrong.  I have been known to use "Dear Firstname Surname" but don't like it.  After the first exchange, see how they sign off their reply - If they sign off with a given name, and use a fairly informal tone, then switch to "Hi Firstname" by all means.  By way of context, I normally sign emails "Chris", and expect "Hi Chris" or "Dear Chris" as the conversation progresses.

Of course, when dealing with older correspondents, or some cultures, you may need to stay more formal.